# About the queue deletion memory in c language

Tags: arrays, c, queue

I am learning the DS.When I am studying queue,I have dilemma about the dequeue of queue.
if we delete the element from the queue it is **deleted permanently** or not, By using array.

```
void dequeue (q*p){

  int a;
  if(isempty(queue)){
      printf("the queue is empty\n");
  }
  else{
      p->f++;
      a=p->arr[p->f];
  }
  printf("%d is dequeued\n",a);
}
```

here why *can't* I use **free(a)** to free the memory.

Comment: Check the argument that being passed to the `isempty()` function. When the queue is indeed empty I think you want to print "The queue is EMPTY" and also not executing the second `printf()` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `int a` as a local variable within your function `dequeue`. A local variable of type int cannot be `free`d; there is no memory obtained through a `malloc`. It contains a single int, and the lifetime / memory of this int will automatically end when the variable goes out of scope (i.e. when function `dequeue` returns).

And: you cannot delete an element out of an array of integer values. An array of type, for example `int[10]`, is a continuous chunk of memory and cannot be split / rearranged that way. It will reserve space for 10 ints regardless whether you "need" each of them or not.

Comment: sir . you means to say that if I declare "**a**" dynamically by using malloc then I can free it right.